# In which countries has Persepolis been banned?

Tags: french-language, censorship, persepolis, marjane-satrapi

Given its unflattering depiction of life in a certain type of society, I'm guessing that *Persepolis* may have been banned in more than one country in the past, but I'm not sure where to find this information.

**In which countries has the book *Persepolis* ever been banned?**

Comment: "Given its unflattering depiction of life in a certain type of society" could you be more specific?

Comment: @Hamlet Not sure how that would improve the question. Anyone who's read the book will already know what kind of society it depicts and how.

Comment: cause you are apparently guessing that the book might be banned, but you haven't really given us much to justify that guess. Questions work best here when there is some sort of research answers can follow up on.

Comment: @Hamlet Do I need to justify my guess? If the answer is "no, it's never been banned anywhere", then fine. I'm now tempted to edit out all of the question body except the last line, which would still leave a valid question without containing any unjustified claims (leave the claims for the answers).

Comment: @Hamlet - I can think of at least one country where it was "banned" - the USA! At the school system level, admittedly - free speech protections would render a national ban all but unworkable - but even so.

Comment: But more literally, Lebanon banned it for a little while, worrying that it could cause political offense.

Comment: Most curiously, some countries have had wildly in consistent policies. UAE banned the comic book, *and* the DVDs - but allowed the film!